# Single public IP for service but failover distribution to two internal IP's

Tags: web-services, azure, virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services, azure-traffic-manager

can anyone tell me if it is possible to set up failover in azure with single public address for the service?

meaning  that if I want the public ip address for a service always to remain the same but have it distributed to two internal ip addresses depending on failover or priority status of these two internal IP's?   Is this possible?  If so  how?

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible, you can front-end your two internal ip addresses with a load balancer which will have public IP.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-overview/

Comment: Azure Traffic Manager can *not* redirect traffic to an internal IP address. It can only flow traffic to external-facing ip:port.

Comment: Got it. IP Addresses within Vnet can not be reached. Took out Azure traffic manager from my post above. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-overview/